# How to make glossy material reflect spotlights into volume?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, volumetrics

I want to be able to create a nice spotlight effect with a spotlight being shone on a mirror or some sort, and be able to see these reflections through a volume scatter, I've tried a few times to get this to work but it just doesn't reflect and will just scatter once hitting the ground
[image]

I've done lots of things like make it have 0 roughness but that reflects everything above

[image]

and I've tried in other scenes and attempted disabling the original light sources volume scatter visibility and that just shows a scatter effect

[image]

What I was wanting is something like

[image]

I don't really want to have to create more lights under the glossy surface to mimic the effect.

Comment: For that effect to work you would need to enable Reflective Caustics, which Cycles doesn't excel at. Even if you enable them I'm not sure the current engine supports reflection caustics over volumetric materials, but I may be wrong

Comment: interesting, I seem to remember trying to enable caustics as I remember using them before, is there any workaround, I don't really want to have to create more lights under the glossy surface to mimic the effect

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39663/laser-beam-pathway-with-reflective-mirrors https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/making-a-laser-in-cycles-straight-beam-of-light https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53548/using-nodes-for-laser-line https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150277/how-to-visualize-reflection-of-a-beam-or-ray https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62750/laser-scanner-shadowing

Comment: You can either use try blender-octane-edition(free/paid), or check out this video https://youtu.be/Sbfj7A7jqTo. I know this video is weird but, I think it suits for the purpose